# Oracle: Insert constant numbers for a set of records and reiterate with incremented value

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

The requirement is to insert a constant number (say 1) in column A for 6 incrementing values in column B in a cycle. This set of 6 values will repeat as designed in the sequence and trigger, once maximum value of 6 is reached. However, the column A should consist of another incremented constant number (say 2) for next set of column B values and so on.

I am new to Oracle PL/SQL and triggers. I searched for a solution but couldn't get what is required. Can anyone please suggest some keywords based upon which I can find relevant information in web or share some ideas about how to resolve this?

Comment: Column A is present as primary key in another table and is present as foreign key in the table meant for above scenario.

Comment: You should give an example. Also, some code if possible.

Answer (score 1):

> "Column A is present as primary key in another table and is present as
>   foreign key in the table"

There is no easy way to count the number of instances of COL_B for each value in COL_A in the child table, because of the mutating trigger error: we cannot select rows from table T1 in a trigger built on T1.

This means storing the current values of COL_A and COL_B in another table, which it turns out you have. Effectively the referenced table is a code control table.  This is a valid design providing you accept that inserting into the child table *is a serialized process* because you need a lock on the parent table.

Here is a worked example: T23 is the child table, T23_CTRL stores the current values.

```
create table t23 (id number, col_a number, col_b number);

create table t23_ctrl (col_a number, col_b number);

insert into t23_ctrl values (1, 0);
```

This trigger maintains the columns in both tables.

```
create or replace trigger t23_trg
    before insert or update  on t23
    for each row
declare
    ctrl t23_ctrl%rowtype;
begin
    select * into ctrl
    from t23_ctrl
    for update;
    if 6 * ctrl.col_a = ctrl.col_b
    then
       ctrl.col_a := ctrl.col_a +1;
       ctrl.col_b := 0;
    end if;
    ctrl.col_b := ctrl.col_b + ctrl.col_a;

    update t23_ctrl t
    set t.col_a = ctrl.col_a
       , t.col_b = ctrl.col_b;

    :new.col_a := ctrl.col_a;
    :new.col_b := ctrl.col_b;

end;
/
```

Here is a test:

```
SQL> insert into t23 (id)
  2  select level 
  3  from dual
  4  connect by level <= 14
  5  /

14 rows created.

SQL> select * from t23 
  2  /

        ID      COL_A      COL_B
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          1          1
         2          1          2
         3          1          3
         4          1          4
         5          1          5
         6          1          6
         7          2          2
         8          2          4
         9          2          6
        10          2          8
        11          2         10
        12          2         12
        13          3          3
        14          3          6

14 rows selected.

SQL> select * from t23_ctrl
  2  /

      COL_A      COL_B
 ---------- ----------
          3          6

SQL>
```

---

Maybe this is not what you're expecting.  If so, please expand your answer (use the *Edit* feature) to include sample output.

Comment: Thank you @APC for your concern and time. The select * from t23 should yield in cyclical values of column B i.e. from 1 to 6 for each unique set of column A values. Moreover, in the begin block of the trigger, can you please help me in understanding what's the purpose of- "if 6 * ctrl.col_a = ctrl.col_b"

Comment: Thank you for your explanation: I will rewrite my example to fit your clarification.  Next time please take the time to frame a decent question, including sample data and expected output, to prevent wasted effort.

Comment: I am sorry for the inconvenience. Thank you for your solution. With what you have provided, I found the exact required solution i.e. CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER INSERT_TRIGGER_XYZ
AFTER INSERT
ON TABLE2
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
INSERT INTO TABLE1 (Col_A, Col_B) 
       SELECT :NEW.Col_A as Col_A
             ,TABLE3.Col_X as Col_B
         FROM TABLE3 ORDER BY Col_B ASC;
END;
/